# Movie or book where main character describes human jobs to alien

Tags: story-identification

Sorry about this very very vague question, but this is all I can remember. There is this guy that is explaining to an (alien?) what we humans do with our time, what jobs do we have, in which things do we work, etc.

I believe this was sort of a funny scene because the dialog was something like this:

- Alien: so, what do you (humans) do?
- Human: well, like 5% of us work in science and the improvement of mankind.
- Alien: and the others?
- Human: uh, maintenance.

The punchline here was "maintenance", as in "the rest of us just go from here to there doing nothing interesting or important".

Honestly, I don't remember if this was a book, movie or TV series, and probably I never saw this, but a friend told me :/

thanks in advance!

Comment: Was it a book perhaps? I seem to remember a scene in Speaker for the Dead where someone was talking to a Piggie in the forest about jobs. Have you read that book? Sorry I can't give more details or try to fully answer - just my faint memories overlapping with yours

Comment: Haven't read it myself, but it's possible that someone shared that with me. I'll look into that book. Thanks!